# Powershell is slow to start and will not show the working path

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

When I fired up powershell it used to look something like this

[image]

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 on my machine, and now I have two issues with Powershell. Firstly, it takes a little over 10 seconds from the time I click on powershell to the time I have a usable prompt. Secondly, there is no display of where on the machine I am.

[image]

This location is actually c:\users\Rory\, but it won't show me that. If I change directories (cd.. etc) navigation works but my prompt still shows PS>

Any way to change this?

Comment: In the first prompt you are running the PowerShell as the built-in Administrator user.  In the second example you are not.  Given I know nothing about how your users are setup, I will put money on the fact, the Rory user isn't an Administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second picture looks like [Default prompt](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847739.aspx):

> THE DEFAULT PROMPT
>
> The default prompt appears only when the Prompt function generates  an
>   error or does not return an object.
>
> The default Windows PowerShell prompt is:
>
> ```
> PS>
> ```
>
> For example, the following command sets the Prompt function to  $null,
>   which is invalid. As a result, the default prompt appears.
>
> ```
> PS C:\> function prompt {$null}
> PS>
> ```
>
> Because Windows PowerShell comes with a built-in prompt, you  usually
>   do not see the default prompt.

You can get `Prompt` function body like this:

```
(Get-Command Prompt).Definition
```

or

```
$Function:Prompt
```

On my PC this returns:

```
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
# .Link
# http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
```

Maybe something in your profile is causing this issue, try launching PowerShell with `-NoProfile` switch. And check if you have errors in the automatic `$Error` variable.

Comment: it was the profile, I deleted the profile and created a new one. Posh-git had messed it up